# What does D.A. Carson mean about the wrath and the love of God shown in the OT "in experience and types" and made clearer in the NT?

Tags: typology, wrath-of-god

From the *gospel translations* Wiki page on [God's Love and God's Wrath](https://gospeltranslations.org/wiki/God%27s_Love_and_God%27s_Wrath) written originally for the journal [*Bibliotheca Sacra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliotheca_Sacra) by D.A. Carson:

> The reality is that the Old Testament displays the grace and love of God **in experience and types**, and these realities become all the clearer in the New Testament . Similarly, the Old Testament displays the righteous wrath of God **in experience and types**, and these realities become all the clearer in the New Testament. ...

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a definition of typology from [https://victorianweb.org/religion/type/typo10.html#:~:text=Typology%20(or%20typological%20symbolism)%20is,people%20of%20the%20Old%20Testament](https://victorianweb.org/religion/type/typo10.html#:%7E:text=Typology%20(or%20typological%20symbolism)%20is,people%20of%20the%20Old%20Testament)

> Typology (or typological symbolism) is a Christian form of biblical
> interpretation that proceeds on the assumption that God placed
> anticipations of Christ in the laws, events, and people of the Old
> Testament. Typology, which had enormous influence on medieval Europe,
> seventeenth century England, and Victorian Britain, not only provided
> literature and art with powerfully imaginative images but also
> influenced attitudes towards reality and time as well.

What this means is that if you compare pieces of the Old Testament to the life of Jesus, you see similarities which can be used to deepen our understanding of the Old Testament. It assumes that such meaning was intended by God as a form of literary foreshadowing.

As for experience, that means that examples were given in the Old Testament from which we must do the work of interpretation. They have a spiritual meaning which may not be evident without making many logical inferences. Think of it as case law in a country that employs Common Law form of justice. Legal principles must be distilled from the cases in order to define the current understanding of the law. This differs from Statutory Law, where everything is spelled out and there is little room for interpretation.